# Redux-saga : detect a time-consuming async task

Tags: redux, timeout, redux-saga

I am trying to detect when a task takes a long time using `redux-saga`.
`SomeHeavyAsyncFunc` is a task with a varying time consumption, from a few ms to some seconds.
I want to trigger an action when it takes more than a certain amount of time, to show a loader.

However I don't want to race with a delay, I simply want to trigger the loading action only if necessary but I don't want to cancel the action even if its long.

Here is an excerpt of my idea:

```
    const timeOut = yield fork(function* () {
      yield call(delay, 300);
      yield put(isPending());
    });
    // in parallel run the computation
    // it will cancel the timeout after computation is done
    const task = yield fork(function* () {
      const res = yield call(SomeHeavyAsyncFunc);
      yield cancel(timeOut);
      yield put(success());
    });
```

The timeout run in the background. If it is over, it simply put an action that will show a loader. The timeout is cancelled when the task is done, so the loader is not shown if the task was actually fast.

However, this does not seem to work. The pending action is triggered only if the action more than 300ms in this exemple. However, it is not triggered as soon as the delay is over but later, so the loader only show up very late.

Does somebody have a working example on this ? Maybe my saga is wrong but what I ask is simply undoable using redux (due to reducer computation time) ?

Comment: Your code should work just fine. Are you sure the action is fired after the delay? (eg. if you `console.time` before and after the call to delay, would it print more than 300 ?) If the spinner takes time to appear, maybe the UI is updating more nodes than needed, making it slow ? Finally, are there any other things going in your app while your async function is waiting for results ? Also, i see your `task` is forked: does the saga do more work after forking it ?

Comment: Yep it does work actually, that's indeed my whole electron app that freezes due to heavy computation. I think that I am doing to much stuffs in the renderer process, I'll try to investigate. Do you have specific tools to improve perfs, except for the dev console ?